# Original error: Error executing adbExec. error while starting app on phone through appium

Tags: android, appium

I use:

- Appium 1.13.0
- Phone: Samsung S8
- Android version: 9

If I try to start app through Appium on phone-got error:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'name' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\pathtoadb\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 45678888 shell am start -W -n appname -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability

Comment: Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting.

Comment: Check if you have internet premissions in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a bare working configuration for real Pixel Android Device

```
{
  "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "8.1",
  "deviceName": "Pixel",
  "appPackage": "com.disney.wdw.android.debug",
  "appActivity": "com.disney.wdpro.park.activities.LoaderActivity",
  "udid": "<unique_identifier>
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Your **UDID** can be located when you access *adb devices* on your terminal/cmd.
2. You can replace appPackage and appActivity with **app** capability where you indicate the path where your apk resides.
3. **deviceName** is required but I believe Appium ignores it for real devices.
4. I suggest you use latest version of Appium Desktop or CLI.
5. You can use default Appium for automationName as your automation engine, mine I use UIAutomator2, adjust it to your preference.

Refer to Appium main site for full documentation of capability usage.
http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UIAutomator2 then you can set this capability "appWaitForLaunch : false", by default it is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind that error is lack of proper permission from developer options or we have to disable some options which is preventing the apps to install in real devices.

We have enable these options:

1. USB debugging.
2. Install via USB.
3. USB Debugging (Security settings).

With the above setting in MIUI and POCO devices need some extra settings to be disabled to make this error go i.e. disable following options:

1. Verify apps over USB.
2. Verify bytecode of debuggable apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your adb here’s how you do it go to the terminal or cmd and type this adb kill-server && adb start-server then try launching again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33305478)

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade your Android SDK by Downloading Platform tools version and replace it with existing Platform SDK from android studio. If it doesn't work try this -> Uninstall your Android SDK and re install it .

Answer (score -1):

Try activate settings below in developer options:

- USB Debugging
- Install Via USB
- USB debugging(Security settings)
- Disable adb authorization timeout

**If it doesn't solve your problem, please don't hesitate to ask.**